# How can I get the generated HTML from dynamically-inserted elements?

Tags: jquery

I use JQuery to create a dynamic button, when I browse the source code of the webpage, what I see is still JQuery code, such as `$("<input>", { "id": "myid", "type"...`
I hope to see generated button code such as `<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />`
How can I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title></title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("<input>", { "id": "myid", "type": "button", "value": "Confirm", "name": "comfire" }).appendTo("#tablemsgbox");
        $("#myid").click(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });  
</script>
</head>  

<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    <div id="tablemsgbox">
    </div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: If you use a tool like Firebug, it should show up in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the source shows the original page generated by the server, but won't show you any DOM manipulations done via javascript. If you want to see the state of the DOM after js manipulation, use tools like Firebug for Firefox, Chrome Inspector, or IE developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the HTML of the generated element, you just do this:

```
$('#myid')[0].outerHTML
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/pVXaj/)  Results will vary by browser.

However, if you're thinking that you can right-click the page, click View Source, and see the inserted element in place with the rest of the source, that's not going to happen.

HTML source is a serialized representation of the DOM.  The browser parses HTML into in-memory data structures that represent the DOM and then works with that.  Anything you do to the DOM afterword (via script) will not be reflected in the 'source' because that's not what your script has affected.  What Firebug (or any other dev tool) is showing you is the parsed and current state of the DOM.

That said, via `innerHTML`/`outerHTML`, you can ask the browser to *re-serialize* the DOM into HTML.  However, the re-serialized HTML is not guaranteed to be the same as your original source – even if you never modify the DOM with script – because things can and will shift around during parsing; this is the nature of HTML's forgiveness of sloppy markup.

In fact—as an extreme example—if you're silly enough to serve your webpage as [XML with an XSLT transform](http://www.sketchers.com/)<sup>1</sup>, the re-serialized HTML will look *absoluely nothing like* the original source code.

However, if you want to see the re-serialized representation of the current state of the entire DOM, look at the string you get from here:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Never do this.  [Seriously.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Sketchy-Skecherscom.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! but I can't find it the source code <input id="myid" type="button" value="Confirm" name="comfire"> at http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/pVXaj/ ,and Firebug can do it.